# How am I able to pass these arguements that refer to a different function?

Tags: lua

I don't have a problem with the code itself. I'm just curious on how this actually works.

Here's the code

```
Vector2 = {
    x = 0, y = 0,

    mt = {},

    New = function()
        local vec = {}

        vec.x = Vector2.x
        vec.y = Vector2.y
        vec.mt = Vector2.mt
        vec.Translate = Vector2.Translate

        return vec
    end,

    Translate = function(self, dx, dy)
        self.x = self.x + dx
        self.y = self.y + dy
    end
}

v1 = Vector2.New()
v1.x = 10
v1.y = 20 
v1.Translate(v1, 10, 10)
print(v1.x, v1.y)
```

This code is in an early stage. I'm about to learn about meta-tables. This code might not be smart, but I'm following a Lua tutorial and I'm just curious about how this works.

From my understanding, `v1 = Vector2.New` is setting `v1` as an identifier to call the `New` function from my table.

What I don't understand is how can I pass the argument through my `v1.Translate()` that alters translate?

I would have thought `v1.Translate` would be referring to the New function not searching the entire table for the Translate function.

--Update: Is this saying go to the Vector2 table, find the New function, and run the Translate function with the New functions values not editing the Vector2 tables values, only the New function values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow :)

In your code `v1 = Vector2.New()` will perform a call to `Vector2.New` and whatever that function returns is assigned to `v1`.

Since the `Vector2.New` function returns a vec (`return vec`), `v1` looks like this:

```lua
v1 = {
    x = 0, -- this is a default, because Vector2.x == 0
    y = 0, -- another default because of Vector2.y
    mt = {}, -- this is a reference to the same table in Vector2.mt
    Translate = Vector2.Translate, -- this is a function, the Vector2.Translate function, functions are first-class values in Lua
}
```

So when you call `v1.Translate`, you're calling the same function as `Vector2.Translate`.

So when you do `v1.Translate(v1, 10, 10)`, you're actually doing `Vector2.Translate(v1, 10, 10)`. But this is *not* because of a metatable magic. This is because you have defined `v1.Translate` to be equal to `Vector2.Translate`.

**Functions are first-class values**

Remember, functions are first-class values in Lua. This means you can pass them around just like numbers, strings and tables.

If you really wanted to, you could do this (the equivalent to `v1.Translate(v1, 10, 10)`):

```lua
translateFn = v1.Translate
translateFn(v1, 10, 10)
```

**Syntactic sugar**

Instead of providing `v1` twice in `v1.Translate(v1, 10, 10)`, you can do this: `v1:Translate(10, 10)`.

When Lua sees the use of a colon (`:`) instead of a dot (`.`), it will provide the identifier on the left-hand-side (`v1`) as the first argument to the function.

It functions entirely the same as `v1.Translate(v1, 10, 10)`, except that `v1:Translate(10, 10)` is 1000x cleaner.

This is called "[syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)":

> Syntactic sugar is syntax within a programming language that is designed to make things easier to read or to express. It makes the language "sweeter" for human use: things can be expressed more clearly, more concisely, or in an alternative style that some may prefer.

Hope that helps!